# No programs will launch after disconnect from a internet network

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xfce, networkmanager

I'm using Arch Linux + Xfce.

When I disconnect from a internet network(WiFi or Wire), no programs will run and gets me following error:

```
[kamix@localhost ~]$ gedit
No protocol specified

** (gedit:5064): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:5064): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Comment: Is it possible that dhcpcd is changing your hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` with this content :

```
[main]
plugins = keyfile

[keyfile]
hostname = <your-host-name>
```

You must replace your hostname(like `localhost`) with `<your-host-name>`.